# Central Limit Theorem for m-dependent stationary random variables in $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: central-limit-theorem, time-series, random-functions, skorohod-space

I am currently writing my master thesis and have a problem with Lemma 2.5 in http://www.math.utah.edu/~rice/berkeshorvathrice2012.pdf . I have to show that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor Nx \rfloor}<X_{i,m},\Phi_{\ell,m}>_{L^2[0,1]} \longrightarrow \sqrt{\lambda_{\ell,m}}W_{\ell}(x) $$ holds for $N \to \infty$ and any index $\ell$, where the convergence is in the Skorokhod space $D[0,1]$. $W_{\ell}$ is a Wiener process, $(\Phi_{\ell,m})_\ell$ is a ONS in $L^2[0,1]$, $x \in [0,1]$ and $X_{i,m}$ is a $L^2[0,1]$ valued random variable. We already know that $(<X_{i,m},\Phi_{\ell,m}>)_{i}$ is m-dependent and 
$$<c_m(t,\cdot),\Phi_{\ell,m}>=\lambda_{\ell,m}\Phi_{\ell,m}(t)$$ with 
$$c_m(t,s)=\mathbb{E}\left[X_{0,m}(t)X_{0,m}(s)\right] + \sum\limits_{i=1}^m \mathbb{E}\left[X_{0,m}(t)X_{i,m}(s)\right]+ \sum\limits_{i=1}^m \mathbb{E}\left[X_{i,m}(t)X_{0,m}(s)\right]$$ holds. My approach is the following theorem from DasGupta:

> Let $(X_i)_i$ be a stationary m-dependent
>   sequence. Let $E(X_i ) = \mu$ and $Var(X_i ) = \sigma^2 < \infty$. Then
>   $\sqrt{n}(\overline{X} − \mu)
>  \longrightarrow N(0, \tau^2)$, where $τ^2 = σ^2 + 2\sum_{i=2}^{m+1}
> Cov(X_1, X_i )$.

So I can get the $\lambda$'s but I don't see where the Wiener process comes from.

Comment: To me, the hard part is replacing the Cramer-Wold step with whatever it takes in Hilbert space.  The Wiener process comes from Donsker's invariance principle (aka "functional central limit theorem") and is present in the 1 dimensional iid version of your problem.  Your goal is to replace iid with $m$-dependent (as is done in the paper you cite) and the finite dim. vector valued process with a Hilbert space.